# EXCEL VBA - Similar function to excel formula Value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA so I got a problem trying to convert some string number to a value number for a IF validation.

The problem is. I have Column "A" filled with something like this:

E/B: Houses 01

E/B: Houses 02

E/B: Building/New Villa

E/B: Building/Bella Casa

E/B: Houses 03

So, in my code, I want it to fill the "B" Column with the last 2 numbers if there's numbers or the name if there isn't.

```
Set Rng = Range("A8:A" & Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

For Each celula In Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Select Case True
        Case IsNumeric(Right(celula, 2)) = True
            celula.Offset(0, 1).Value = Right((celula), 3)
        Case Else
            celula.Offset(0, 1).Value = Mid(celula, InStr(4, celula, "/") + 1, Len(celula))
    End Select
Next celula
```

But the Case IsNumeric(Right(celula, 2)) = True is never True. It do not capture the 2 last numbers. But it works alright with the names and returns "New Villa" and "Bella Casa". And I think the problem is that Right(celula, 2) is never a number, even if theres a number.

I want to know if theres a way to convert "Right(celula, 2)" in a Value, just like the =Value formula in excel, to do the validation.

OBS: Before trying this way, I had a excel formula applied to those cells and it worked, but I want to try this way for learning purposes.

Thanks

Comment: Just copied & pasted both your code and your sample data into a new Excel worksheet and it works. You sure you don't have whitespace(s) after the numbers? `Debug.Print "<" + Right(celula, 2) + ">"` to make sure (it should print `<01>`, `<02>`, etc.).

Comment: Looks good. use this to test it out. May be you are not selecting the correct range.
For Each celula In Selection
    Select Case True....

Comment: I set the rgn after an autofilter, that was the problem. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `for each` loop itself works as expected.

However, this

`Set Rng = Range("A8:A" & Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)`

is probably where the problem lies. You have to make sure you've got the correct `Range`. You can verify by debugging: `Debug.print Rng.Address`.

Comment: The range is ok, it works with the names. If the range were off, it should return nothing.

Edit: I have other data in my sheet, "I" column is filled but not used in this.

Comment: what does it print for `rng.address`?

Comment: There should be anything else, it works as expected in a separate sheet, but only case else works in my main sheet

Comment: Yeah, the problem has to do with the range. It shows $A$7:$A$8, but why it works for the building names? I dont get it. Well, thanks

Comment: Found the solution. I set the Rng after an autofilter.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub t()
Dim rng As Range

With ActiveSheet
    Set rng = .Range("a1:a" & .Range("a" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        For Each cell In rng.Cells

            If Val(Right(cell.Value, 2)) = 0 Then
                        cell.Offset(0, 1) = Mid(cell.Value, InStrRev(cell.Value, "/") + 1, Len(cell))
                    Else
                        cell.Offset(0, 1) = Val(Right(cell.Value, 2))
            End If

        Next cell
End With     

End Sub
```